# why i lost name of my my new joomla hello world extension in components menu?

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

I just made my new joomla3.1 hello world extension using discover extension method i install it. BUT after installation i am unable to locate extension name in joomla component menu.

i already tried this link its working fine.

```
http://localhost/COM/administrator/index.php?option=com_process
```

anticipating helpful response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- $Id$ -->
<extension type="component" version="3.1" method="upgrade">
    <name>COM_PROCESS_NAME</name>
    <author>Arslan Tahir</author>
    <creationDate>25 DEC 2013</creationDate>>
    <copyright>GPL</copyright>
    <license></license>
    <auhtorEmail>aaa@outlook.com</auhtorEmail>
    <version>1</version>
    <description>COM_PROCESS_DESCRIPTION</description>



    <administration>
        <files>
        <filename>index.html</filename>
        <filename>process.php</filename>
        </files>
        <menu>COM_PROCESS_NAME</menu>
    </administration> 
</extension>
```

Comment: i just found my extension in extension manager->manage   but not visible in component menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had this a couple times where the menu item was disabled because of disabling/uninstalling a component and then it not reappearing when the component was upgraded or installed. Likely there is a menu item for it in the `#__menu` table. Search the table for your component's name (`com_helloworld`?) as the title. Should find an item there. Make sure that published is set to 1 and that the component_id matches the id for the component in the #__extensions table.

Comment: thanks buddy. you are genius. in #__menu table it was showing component_id=0. It started working just after i changed that ID. once again thanks David.

Comment: and i think solution to these time wasting bugs should be incorporated in joomla. . .

Comment: Totally agree. But one of us actually has to take the extra time to do it. I'm glad this will at least be on Stack so eventually you can google it and find the solution. There likely is a check to build the menu in the install process that needs to be optimized a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a new entry for your component in the **#__extensions** table.