# language file in joomla is not working properly?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.1

```
http://127.0.0.1/COM/administrator/index.php?option=com_process_name
```

when i click on my newly created component form components menu "com_process_name" should be translated from language.ini file but joomla 3.1 is not translating that file properly as shown above.

my com.process.sys_language.ini file

```
COM_PROCESS_NAME="Hello World"
```

but when I watch it from extension Manager->manage it shows its proper name  Hello World

I am using JOOMLA 3.1.5

my manifest file

```
<extension type="component" version="3.1" method="upgrade">
    <name>COM_PROCESS_NAME</name>
    <author>Arslan Tahir</author>
    <creationDate>25 DEC 2013</creationDate>
    <copyright>GPL</copyright>
```

thats how i am including language file

```
    <languages folder="components/com_process">
               <language tag="en-GB">en-GB/en-GB.com_process.ini</language>
               <language tag="en-GB">en-GB/en-GB.com_process.sys.ini</language>
        </languages>
```

Comment: or form where we can watch installed joomla language files

Comment: So you want the URL to be translated by the language string?

Comment: i want that the name of component should be translated form language file. and it is doing when i try to watch it in extension manager. but in links its not translating it.

Comment: It's not supposed to be translated in links. It will always stay as com_process_name

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18986989/why-i-lost-name-of-my-my-new-joomla-hello-world-extension-in-components-menu/18991135#18991135 prereq of this question

Comment: @ lodder but my actual administration part of my component is at 127.0.0.1/COM/administrator/index.php?option=Hello_World

Comment: thanks lodder actually i was tangled between a video lecture and joomla docs MVC. i oslved it by COM_HELLOWORLD="Hello World Extension"   and yhou were right these links were not supposed to be translated

Comment: thanks for giving time to my question.

Comment: make your comment as answer @Lodder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URl used to view your component such as:

```
index.php?option=com_process_name
```

is generated by the component name `com_process_name` which cannot be translated. Anywhere else on Joomla, it can be

Comment: would creating a menu alias so that '/processname' redirected to ?option=com_process_name fix the issue?

Comment: The best thing to do would be to enable SEF URL's